# What preposition is correct 'sleep on the bed' or 'sleep in the bed'

Tags: prepositions

Are both expressions correct? If yes, do they have different meanings? It seems to me that I came across both of them in books, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sleep in bed or sleep on bed](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59790/sleep-in-bed-or-sleep-on-bed)

Comment: Note that there's an idiomatic phrase "in bed", without an article ("time to get in bed", "he's in bed with..."); there's no similar phrase *"on bed".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are both correct, but convey slightly different ideas.

> I will sleep **on** a bed.

Implies that I will sleep on the piece of furniture I refer to as a bed.  As opposed to sleeping on the couch or sleeping on the floor.

> I will sleep **in** a bed

Specifically conveys the idea that I will be inside the bedclothes, typically underneath a blanket or duvet.

Comment: +1, but "bedclothes" is a new one to me. Had to look that up. Would normally call that "bedding", "sheets", "covers", or "blankets".

Comment: Ha, now you've drawn my attention to it, it is an odd sounding word - like clothes to dress the bed in!  Maybe it's a north UK thing - growing up, it's what my mother and grandmothers always called them.  Looked it up, it's pretty old - apparently from when 'clothes' was still the plural of 'cloth'.  So I guess it makes a little more sense in that context.

Comment: In tropical countries, some places are so hot that we never use the bedding clothes to sleep in. So does it mean literally we don't sleep in bed?

Answer (score 27):

Both expressions are correct and can have different meanings. A bed usually is made of a surface for sleeping upon and a warm cover of some kind. The phrase **on the bed** would be taken to imply that something is placed upon both. Take this example:

> I placed my luggage **on the bed**.

This would mean the luggage was placed upon the top of the upper surface of the bed and bedding.

The phrase **in the bed** would be taken that something is placed between the warm covering (or bed cover) and above the sleeping surface. It is placed **inside** the bed, as illustrated by this example:

> The hot water bottle was placed **in the bed**.

If the hot water bottle was placed **on the bed** it would get cold and not warm the bed properly.

Thus if we use **sleep** as the action being performed, you can see that we can both **sleep in the bed** and **sleep on the bed**. For example:

> He was too drunk to **sleep in the bed** and was found **sleeping on it**.

---

There is a very famous *bed in* event which can also be used to illustrate the difference:

This is *John and Yoko* **on the bed**:

[image: Wikipedia image of John and Yoko]

This is *John and Yoko* **in the bed**:

[image: Image of John and Yoko]
<sub>(source: [resolver.kb.nl](http://resolver.kb.nl/resolve?urn=urn:gvn:ANP01:15397082&role=image&size=variable))</sub>

Comment: +1 for the picture, although I think this answer makes the distinction seem more significant and more clear-cut than it actually is in practical usage.

Answer (score 3):

Sleeping in the bed would actually mean to be inside the bed(covered by under the sheets") however, Sleeping on the bed logically mean laying on the bed on the surface of it, don't go deep into the holy crap of English literature.

**Conclusion**: *

> "Sleeping in the bed", is correct one to use.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, one would say IN bed when they are going to go to sleep.
But before sleeping or after waking up, you can say:

> I'm sleeping (**in** bed)
>   I'm **in** bed reading
>   I'm **in** bed watching the TV
>   I'm **in** bed having tea and breakfast

The OP's example

> (to) sleep **in the bed**

the article ‘the’ suggests that the listener knows which bed is mentioned; or  there is only one available bed in which to sleep. The preposition **in** tells us the person is under the covers, *sandwiched* between the mattress and the bedsheets.

> (to) sleep **on the bed**

suggests the same as the above with the exception that the person is lying **on top** of the bed.

Comment: Community Wiki post, if something should be added to the answer feel free  to jump IN.