# 'Lie down into bed' or 'Lie down in bed'?

Tags: prepositions

I know that 'I'm in bed.' is correct. I also know that 'lie down' is (also) a transfer verb, in that one assumes the horizontal position in bed either when already being in bed, or coming from out of bed.

So please tell me whether I'm right when saying that each of the following is correct for its own meaning:

'Lie down in bed' = assume the horizontal position when already being in bed.

'Lie down into bed' = assume the horizontal position in bed, coming from out of bed.

Many thanks.

Comment: No, you're mistaken. *Lie down into bed* is not idiomatically valid. As [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Lie+down+into+bed%2CLie+down+in+bed%2CLay+down+into+bed%2CLay+down+in+bed%2CGet+in+bed%2CGet+into+bed&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows, we usually say ***Get** in/to/into bed* anyway, or more rarely ***Lay/Lie down in** bed*. The main difference is ***in / into*** are normally only used *near* the bed, whereas ***to*** can be used when the bed is in another room or even further away.

Comment: Thank you, all clear now.

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/79964/9161 and https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/59205/9161

Answer (score 1):

If you used "into" that would mean that you were going into the inside of the bed.  "In bed" is an idiom.  I have heard people say, "get into bed," which means "go to your bed and get in it."

You didn't ask this, but your use of "lie" reminds me of my memory device to remember whether to use "lie" or "lay" in a sentence:  "Lie" has the same vowel sound as "recline," and "lay" has the same vowel sound as "place."  So lying down means reclining and laying something means placing it somewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much  :)